# Сформировать вектор из наибольших значений элементов строк исходной матрицы, состоящей из элементов целого типа

Tags: delphi, pascal

Нужна хелпа (PASCAL ABC), на паскале не шарю особо
Задание: разработать программу решения задачи с использованием библиотечного модуля пользователя, в котором реализовать следующие подпрограммы: 
- инициализация матрицы размерностью N x M ( 1 < n < 50, 1 < M < 50 ) 
- вывод матрицы на экран 
- процедуры ( функции ) обработки матрицы согласно своему варианту.

Задание из варианта:

 Сформировать вектор из наибольших значений элементов строк исходной матрицы, состоящей из элементов целого типа.

```
{__main.pas}
program lr10;
Uses MainUnit;

begin
  CreateMatrix(a);
  PrintMatrix(a);
end.


{ MainUnit.pas }
Unit MainUnit;
Interface
Uses crt;

const
  n = 4;

type
  matrix = array[1..n, 1..n] of integer;

var
  a: matrix;

   {  create of matrix  } 
procedure CreateMatrix(var x: matrix);
var
  j, i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to n do 
    for j := 1 to n do
      x[i, j] := random(n * n) + 1;
end;

{   output of matrix   }
procedure PrintMatrix(x: matrix);
var
  j, i: integer;

begin
  for i := 1 to n do 
  begin
    for j := 1 to n do
      write(x[i, j]:4);      
    writeln;
  end;
end;

function DoMatrix(x: matrix): real;
var
  j, i: integer;
  p: real;

begin
  p := 1;
  for i := 1 to n do 
    for j := 1 to n do
      if j >= n + 1 - i then 
        p := p * x[i, j];
  DoMatrix := p;        
end;

{ =============================== }
{   create matrix   and   multiplication  } 
function DoMatrix(x: matrix): real;
var
  j, i: integer;
  p: real;

begin
  p := 1;
  for i := 1 to n do 
    for j := 1 to n do
      if j >= n + 1 - i then 
        p := p * x[i, j];
  DoMatrix := p;        
end;
```

Comment: Где то, что Вами СДЕЛАНО? В чём именно, в каком моменте, возникла сложность? PS. А на заказ тут программы никто не пишет.

Comment: код прикрепил в правках

Comment: Зачем у Вас два раза функция DoMatrix? К слову, ее можно написать аккуратнее, выкинув "if j>…." и сделав условие вложенного цикла таким: "for j := n + 1 - i to n do "

Comment: Что касается вашей задачи... Вы умеете искать максимальный элемент в массиве? Если да - найдите в каждой строке максимум, и запишите его в итоговый массив с индексом, соответствующим индексу строки.